# How to optimise use of enums in React TypeScript app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums

I have this boolean in my React app: `const isValid = response.headers.get('Content-Type')?.includes('application/json');`

I want to add some enums to improve it like:

```
export enum ResponseHeader {
  CONTENT_TYPE = 'Content-Type',
}
```

And then I can do: `const isValid = response.headers.get(ResponseHeader.CONTENT_TYPE)?.includes('application/json');`.

But what about the value `application/json`. Do I have to create a new `enum` for that, or can I do this in a smatter way?

Answer (score 0):

Same idea:

```
export enum MimeTypeEnum = {
  APPLICATION_JSON = 'application/json'
  // ...
}

const isValid = response.headers.get(ResponseHeader.CONTENT_TYPE)?.includes(MimeTypeEnum.APPLICATION_JSON)
```